# Is it possible to set groupFooterTemplate although row is hidden?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

1. Is it possible to set groupFooterTemplate although row is hidden?
   I want to hide a row when I'm grouping the results by column but still showing the GroupFooterTemplate.
2. I have two columns about total In footerTemplate. so I want to show the balance (like 1st total column - 2nd total column). is it possible?

   ```
   group: {
               field: "BIL_Month", aggregates: [
                   { field: "BIL_Debit", aggregate: "sum" },
                   { field: "BIL_Credit", aggregate: "sum" },
               ]
           },
   aggregate: [
               { field: "BIL_Debit", aggregate: "sum" },
               { field: "BIL_Credit", aggregate: "sum" }
           ],                
       },
   columns: [

           { field: "BIL_Month", title: "Month", template: '<div class="month">#=BIL_Month#<div>', footerTemplate: "Total" },
           { field: "BIL_Debit", title: "Debit",  template: '<div class="debit" style="font-size:12px text-align:center;">#=BIL_Debit#<div>', groupFooterTemplate: "#=sum#", footerTemplate: "#=sum#" },
           { field: "BIL_Credit", title: "Credit", template: '<div class="credit" style="font-size:12px text-align:center;">#=BIL_Credit#<div>', groupFooterTemplate: "#=sum#", footerTemplate: "#=sum#" },

       ],
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean show footer when collapsing, then there is `groupable.showFooter` option:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    ...
    groupable: {
        showFooter: true
    },
    ...
});
```